# Can I check if there are subclasses and get their name?

Tags: php, oop

I'ld like to check if my class has subclasses and get their name. Is it possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-classes will have to be loaded for this to work. First, get an array of classes that PHP knows about, using `get_declared_classes()`.

Then, iterate through that array, and use `is_subclass_of` on each, to test whether it is a sub-class of the parent class you wish to test.

If your child classes are not necessarily loaded, you could scan a folder for a certain pattern using `glob()` e.g. `"lib/*php"`, and load found files with `require_once()`.

Answer (score 0):

This function will give all the subclasses in a class.

```
function getSubclassesOf($parent) { 

     $result = array(); 
     foreach (get_declared_classes() as $class) { 
           if (is_subclass_of($class, $parent)) $result[] = $class; 
     }
     return $result; 
}
```